# Game of life, stable configuration

Tags: c

I need to show after how many steps or generation) my cells matrix is stable(it repeats its configuration). I've already have nr_neirborhood function that calculates the cell neirborhoods and the initialization function that alocates dinamically my matrix from the input file. I really would apreciatte your help.

I've tried to compare the actual cells matrix with the first one and see if they are equal. But've I found out that my actual matrix can be the same as a previous one, not just the first. How can I memorize dinamically all the previous matrix?

```
void obtion_stabile(int **matrix, FILE *p_in, FILE *p_out, int steps) {
    int N, M, buff[1024];
    char ch; //character for enter
    fscanf(p_in, "%d", &N); fscanf(p_in, "%d", &M); //read dimension of the matrix 

    fscanf(p_in, "%c", &ch); //read the enter
    matrice = initialization(matrice, N, M, p_in); //allocate dinamically the matrix from the input file
    int **copy = NULL; copy = alocare(matrice, N, M); //copy is the first matrix, the one read from the file
    int **next = NULL; next = alocare(next, N, M); //next is the matrix where I memorize if a cell live in the next generation or it dies, it depends on the number of the neiborhood
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
            copy[i][j] = matrix[i][j];
    }
    int ok = 1; //variable that verify if the actual matrix is equal to the first one
    for (int k = 0; k < steps; k++) {
         for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
                int neirborhood = 0; //for each cell I calculate its neiborhood
                neirborhood = nr_neirborhood(matrix, i, j, N, M);
                switch (neirborhood)
                {
                case 2:
                    next[i][j] = matrice[i][j]; //it is the same
                    break;

                case 3:
                    next[i][j] = 1;//it is alive
                    break;

                default:
                    next[i][j] = 0;//it dies
                    break;
                }
            }
         }
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
                matrice[i][j] = next[i][j];//after each generation matrix becomes the next one
        }
        if (egality(matrice, copie, N, M)) {
            fprintf(p_out, "Configuration stabile at steps: %d\n", k + 1);
            show(copie, N, M, p_out); ok = 1; 
            break;
        }
        else
            ok = 0;
    }
    if (ok == 0) {
        fprintf(p_out, "there is no stable conifiguration\n"); 
        show(matrice, N, M, p_out);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you also call it stable, if the same configuration is repeated every, say, 100th step?

Comment: If you have wrap-around and flyers, your repeat could be as much as twice your arena size. Something like Floyd's 'tortoise and the hare algorithm' could eventually find your repeat without storing all the configurations.

Comment: in general, the program should keep two versions of the arena.  Use version 'a' to calculate version 'b' then use version 'b' to calculate version 'a', etc  When ever making the switch between arenas, increment a counter.  if version 'a' is the same a version 'b', after updating, then the current configuration is stable

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) use meaningful variable names that indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both)  The current names, like: 'N' and 'M' are meaningless, even in the current context.  2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  3) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  4) separate code blocks: `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` via a single blank line

Comment: Technically every state is stable because there are only a finite number of states. The problem that makes sense is - Is this state stable with a period < k where k is a parameter. So you have to store only k such states (sliding windows). I would also make some sort of a hash to reduce storage and the comparison time.

Comment: (a) What does stable mean? Is a configuration stable only if it repeats after one step (M[i+1] = M[i])? Or is it stable if it repeats after any number of steps (there is some k such that M[i+k] = M[i])? (b) If the latter, what do you need to find, the smallest k for which that holds (the basic size of the loop)? The smallest i for which there is a k for which that holds (the first configuration that is repeated as part of the infinite loop)?

Comment: @Ctx yes, it doesn't care about how big the iteration is

Comment: @EricPostpischil stable mean the smallest k so that M[i+k]=M[i]

Comment: Assuming memory is limited, one way to detect a loop is to march two separate instances, A and B, through the process. Initialize them both to the starting configuration, then step B and compare it to A, then step B again and compare to A, then step A once and repeat. If there is a loop, eventually A and B will be equal. However, this may go well past the first repetition. I expect somebody has studied this problem, but, offhand: Once you find a repetition, you will know how many steps B has progressed beyond A (because you will have kept a count). That number is a multiple of the period.

Comment: Then you could factor it and test the factors (perhaps easier said than done) to determine the fundamental period. Once you know the fundamental period, p, you can find where the cycle started by resetting A and B to the initial state, running B p steps, and then stepping A and B in synchrony until they are equal. If just want to know where the cycle started and not the fundamental period, you can use whatever k you found instead of B while retracing to find the start.

Comment: See [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Tortoise_and_hare) for information on Floyd’s tortoise-and-hare algorithm, Brent’s algorithm, and Gosper’s algorithm. When searching, “loop detection” and “cycle detection” may be useful search terms.